# ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel, blade

**Ruta**

```
<?php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\pagescontrollers@inicio');

//Route::get('fotos/{parametro}', function($variable){ //en la busqueda colocar / OBLIGATORIO //return ('estas en fotos'.$variable); //});

///Route::get('fotos/{parametro?}', function($variable='texto'){
//en la busqueda colocar / OPCIONAL /// return ('estas en fotos'.$variable); // ? lo hace opcionnal //})->where('parametro', '[A-Za-z]+'); // acepta solo texto //no funciona Route::view('url','pagina',['numero'=>'fggfgf']); // y si lo quiero con numeros?

Route::get('plantilla', function () { // name variable de enlace return view('plantilla'); //funciona })->name('foto');

//route::get('fototres/{nombre?}', function($nombre=null){// //})->name('foto');
Route::get('nosotros', function () { // name variable de enlace return view('nosotros'); //funciona });

Route::get('fotos/{nombre?}','App\Http\Controllers\pagescontrollers@personas')->name('nombre');//); Esto presenta problemas
```

**Controlador**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class pagescontrollers extends Controller
{
    public function inicio()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
    public function personas($nombre = null)
    {
        $equipo = ['ignacio', 'juanito']; //return view('fotos',['equipo'=>$equipo],'nombre'=>$nombre); return
        view('fotos', compact('equipo', 'nombre')); //('equip' , 'variable')
        
    }
}

?>
```

**Plantilla**

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>bvbvvbbvbvbvbv</h1>
      <div>cabecera</div>
      <div class="container">   @yield('seccion')  </div>
      <div> fotter</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Archivo**

```
@extends('plantilla') 

@section('seccion') 

<h1> fotos </h1> 
//<a href="{{route('nosotros',$item)}} class="h4 text-danger">{{$item}}</a> 
@foreach($personas) 
    //$this->item = $item->$item; <a href="{{route('nombre',$item)}} class="h4 text-danger">{{$item}}</a> 
@endforeach

@if(!empty($nombre)) 

    @switch($nombre)
        @case($nombre=='ignacio') <h2> el nombre es {{$nombre}} : </h2>
        @break
        
        @case($nombre=='juanito') <h2> el nombre es {{$nombre}} : </h2>
        @break 
    @endswitch 
@endif 

@endsection
```

Comment: De verdad todo el código que pegaste se ocupa para la pregunta?, checa [ask] y trata de proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a StackOverflow en español.
Primero que nada, así no se utiliza `switch-case`, dentro del parámetro `case` solo va el valor con el que se está evaluando la variable que colocas en el `switch`, un ejemplo:

```
// Suponiendo que $nombre = 'Ignacio';
@switch($nombre)
    @case('Fernando')
        El nombre es Fernando.
        Aquí no entra, la variable es 'Ignacio'.
        @break
    @case('Ignacio')
        El nombre es Ignacio.
        Aquí entra.
        @break
@endswitch
```

Segundo, en tu caso no es necesario colocar un switch y case porque lo que imprimes en ambos casos es lo mismo: *`el nombre es {{$nombre}}`*, así que perfectamente puede funcionar solo con el `if`:

```
@if(!empty($nombre))
    el nombre es {{$nombre}}
@endif
```

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones